# My service is running every two minutes and I dont know why

Tags: java, android, android-service

I've got a service that starts in the App.class, like so:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, DevotionalService.class);
JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_NUMBER,componentName)
        .setRequiresCharging(false)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
        .setPersisted(true)
        .setPeriodic(60 * 60 * 1000)
        .build();
JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
if(resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job Scheduled.");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job Scheduling Failed");
}
```

So I've very clearly started `setPeriodic(60 * 60 * 1000)` however in my logcat I can see that its running a lot more frequently than that:

```
08-23 12:33:45.512 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Started
08-23 12:33:45.610 10218-10540/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Job Finished
08-23 12:33:46.124 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: IDs match, nothing to do.
08-23 12:35:13.218 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Started
08-23 12:35:13.299 10218-11257/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Job Finished
08-23 12:35:13.750 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: IDs match, nothing to do.
08-23 12:37:53.262 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Started
08-23 12:37:53.346 10218-12560/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Job Finished
08-23 12:37:53.925 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: IDs match, nothing to do.
08-23 12:42:05.384 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Started
08-23 12:42:05.468 10218-14668/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: Job Finished
08-23 12:42:07.541 10218-10218/com.app.myapp D/DevotionalService: IDs match, nothing to do.
```

Inside the service there are two volley services receiving JSON from a URL.  One of them only gets added to the VolleyQueue if the first one says too.  But as far as I am aware Volley shouldnt have any baring on how frequently the service is run?